# Firefox & Angular: missing script

Tags: angularjs, firefox

I have an angular app that works fine in Chrome & IE. In Firefox, I get the error:

```
Module 'xxxx' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
```

In the network tab, I can see that the app.js script was downloaded. But I can't find the script in the Debugger tab, to put a breakpoint in it. I even added an `alert` in just before I define the module, but the alert doesn't show.

Seems like Firefox is not executing the script for some reason. Any suggestions?

UPDATE: It happens when I include the use of `localStorage` in the script. If I take it out, then I can see the script in the Debugger tab and the app loads.

Comment: can you provide your code in plunkr

Comment: `You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.` is clear. Provide some code if you want some help to fix your issue :)

Comment: @Mistalis did you bother reading the question? If it works in Chrome and IE, would there be a typo? Even if there was a typo, it should still show in the Debugger tab and an alert in the app.js script should still execute.

Comment: @PankajKumar I'm not sure which files to upload - the app.js file (which doesn't get executed at all) or any of the 30 or so controller files that reference the app module.

Comment: Try uploading all files so that I can help you